# Bookmark in Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, hyperlink, flexbox, href, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to insert id bookmarks
(https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark) inside a flexbox div scrolling horizontally.
Each link would lead to separate div's inside the container.

It seems that the links doesn't recognize horizontality...

```
<div class="horizontal-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <h1>BLABLA</h1>
        <h3>BLA</h3>
        <a href="#first">Go to First Chapter</a>
        <a href="#scd">Go to Chapter Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img class="carte" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <h3 id="first">CHAPTER ONE</h3>
        <p>blablabla</p>
        <p>blablabla</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried to link directly to a div's id...
do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you, all

Sorry for a such silly question. I forgot to add padding to my divs...

Thanks !!